# My $PS1 \h is showing as "unknown". Being set in .bash_profile

Tags: command-line, terminal, bash

My `$PS1` in Bash is set to:

```
\[${BOLD}${MAGENTA}\]\u \[$WHITE\]at \[$ORANGE\]\h \[$WHITE\]in \[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\]\$([[ -n \$(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo \" on \")\[$PURPLE\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$WHITE\]
```

But is showing up like:

```
Jesse at unknown2837371d98a2 in ~
```

Why is my hostname (`\h`) showing up as unknown?

Comment: What does `hostname` display? What if you set PS1 to just `\h` for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have such hostname. Please check it using `hostname`.

Comment: How do I change my hostname to something reasonable?

Comment: run `hostname "my-new-hostname"`; if you want that changes will be persistent, you must change configuration file; that name of the config file depends on your distributive (in debian/ubuntu it is /etc/hostname)